mint total supply and ensure no authorize transfer
I have mint account without freeze authority and would like to mint max token supply in different wallets based on tokenomics distribution.
Q1: Can I add token vesting latter to different wallets?
Q2: How to prevent an unauthorized transfer using multi-signer from metamask or others wallet?


If you have no freeze authority, once the tokens are distributed to the wallets, they're completely out of your hands, and you have no control over them to add vesting afterewards.
Avoiding unauthorized transfers is more of a client-side issue. Just be sure to avoid signing transactions to transfer tokens out of your account!

